# How to make apache slow and unreliable?

Tags: apache, testing, apache2, stress-testing

I'm writing some code on a mobile device that uses a REST service to retrieve data from a host. That REST services is being proxied by Apache.  In test mode I would like to be able to simulate network outages (as if the device has lost it's cell connection) to test the applications handling of intermittent failures.  I also need to validate it's behavior with slow network connections.

I'm currently using Traffic Shaper XP to slow the network connection, but now I need something to make the Apache server send connection resets both randomly and on predefined sequences (to setup and repeat specific test scenarios).

Comment: Make it execute PERL scripts via CGI.  That'll slow it down.

Comment: That's not really helpful at all skaffman.

Comment: It's friday afternoon. I'm feeling frivolous.

Comment: Dummynet in freebsd is made for this kind of testing.

Comment: As of OS X 10.7 (Lion) Apple has bundled a tool with XCode called the Network Link Conditioner.  It provides the required functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like DummyNet is the closest thing, but it’s still not quite there. For repeatable testing it would be good to have some control over dropped packets and resets.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy from Shopify:

Download https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy/releases the cli and server

Run the server:

```
 ./toxiproxy-server-linux-amd64
```

On the cli setup proxy to apache on another port e.g. 8080

```
./toxiproxy-cli create apache -l localhost:8080 -u localhost:80
```

Make connection slow and unreliable:

```
./toxiproxy-cli toxic add apache -t latency -a latency=3000 
./toxiproxy-cli toxic add apache -t limit_data -a bytes=1000 --tox=0.01
```

here add 3 second of latency and stop after 1000 bytes for 1% of requests there are other options for bandwidth etc. You can add or remove these during use.  Lots of other features and libraries there.

Answer (score 3):

In Apache2 you can make it slow by adjust prefork settings in apache2.conf. The settings below ought to make apache pretty fn slow. They made my local web application take 700% longer to load.

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareServers       2
    MaxSpareServers      2
    MaxClients          4
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a little proxy that forwards TCP connections from your app to the apache server and that you can set up in your test to cut the connection after x number of bytes or milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

On a different (or on the same) computer use the commandline tool `ab` to get some load on the apache. More informations [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html).

Answer (score -1):

Is this a Unix or Linux environment?  `nice` it up to give it lower priority then run a high CPU usage task like listening to music, playing a movie, calculating pi, etc.  The low priority for Apache should create problems similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: It's a Windows (aaack) environment.

I'm thinking that I may need to standup a Linux VM to really have the control I need.  I'm also thinking that I may need to write an apache module to get the level of control that I want.

Comment: You might be able to do the same thing with Windows.  Just set the priority to lowest (if it lets you), and then run [SuperPI](http://www.xtremesystems.com/superpi/).